# diesel steam engine

Tags: thermodynamics, applied-physics, heat-engine

Let's imagine a diesel engine's cylinder head would be heated by external means, to some hundred degree celsius, and the fuel would be replaced by water.

We've made modifications so that water would'nt destroy the fuel system and the cylinders would sustain the high temperature.

Now the injector would squirt some water into compressed hot air. It would instantly vaporize and the steam expands with the moving piston.

Would this give a working engine? What degree of efficiency can be expected compared to internal combustion?

Comment: [Wikipedia/Oxyhydrogen/Production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen#Production), see the line "The energy required to generate...". There is [syngas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syngas) though, which is modest on the $C$-side for a fuel, if this is what you want to get at. The question is more suited for the chemistry page btw.

Comment: Water to steam requires heat, not just temperature. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat There would be no energy gained by using water. Others have clamed to use Microwaves through a spark plug opening to vaporize water. Condensate mixes with the crankcase oil, causing low lubrication. There was an engine developed in 1936 by "William Still" that used steam on the bottom of an internal combustion engine. It had great stall characteristics and very high thermal efficiency. Abandoned because "the cost of fuel doesn't justify the additional complication of the mechanism".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_engine

Comment: The question is more about if the engine could be driven by external heat instead internal combustion... It is part of the idea to heat up the cylinders by external combustion, by fuel, gas or wood...